# Offensive user profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page

While doing a "First Question" review, I opted to view the user's profile and saw wording that could be offensive. (Personally, I choose to ignore these things and move on.)

Normally, if I come across a question or answer that could be offensive I would flag it for mod attention. But in this case, it is the profile that could be an issue. User profiles are site-wide.

How are offensive user profiles handled?

Comment: Write a custom flag on one of their posts telling us their profile is offensive

Comment: I recently saw a user profile containing threats of death. So I flagged the user's answer and referred to the profile. The same user also threatened myself with death. (But here I still am.)

Comment: @NigelJ I'm glad that you are still alive.  BTW we both have a new monarch, though quite saddened at the passing of Queen Elizabeth II.  It will be very hard to fill her shoes.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I don't think Her Majesty can be 'replaced'. We have reached the end of an era, I would suggest. Things will be different from now on, I feel.